# Gitactions WF : run is limited to 35 days - Is there a workaround?

Tags: github-actions, gitlab-ci

As per documentation a Workflow run time is limited to 35 days at max,
Is there any workaround to extend this duration ?
In our case a WF spans a CI/CD pipe from SIT>UAT>Prod
Large projects can span > 6 months from Dev>Prod. UAT itself can span 30 days.
Unless the entire UAT is over files will not progress to Prod.

Comment: Workaround: Start using self-hosted runners. :-)

Comment: Just to clarify, your workflow is running for 30 days straight without ending?

Comment: @Azeem - We are using self-hosted runners, but this setting is applicable even to self-hosted runners.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti - Actual run time might be just a minute or 2 , but for the rest of the time it is in a stalled state pending approval for the next Job. The Next Job kicks in only after maybe 30 days since that is when it needs to be deployed on the UAT env.

Comment: There is no way to get around this limitation. My suggestion is to change your deployment approach and leverage a concept called [ApproveOps or IssueOps](https://josh-ops.com/posts/github-approveops/). You can use GitHub Issues to provide an asynchronous approval and have deployments runs based off the response in the Issue. This way, you don't have jobs sitting in the queue waiting for approvals.